# Comparing two values of the tables and then updating one of them according to the condition

Tags: sql, oracle

need to Compare the values of one named columns of two different tables.

Table A:-

```
Name Marks
Amit   23
Rahul  12
Gaur   10
```

Table B:-

```
Name Marks
Amit   34
Rahul  10
Gaur   10

Condition:-
marks of A != marks of B
then update in table A 
Marks= A-B
```

Final result will be :-

```
Name Marks
Amit   -11
Rahul   2
Gaur    10
```

Comment: What if there are multiple people named `Amit`(as an example) ?

Comment: there is unique id behind that you can ignore, it will cal for one individual only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO a
USING b
ON (a.name = b.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET marks = a.marks - b.marks
  WHERE a.marks <> b.marks
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (Name, Marks) AS
SELECT 'Amit',  23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rahul', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gaur',  10 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE b (Name, Marks) AS
SELECT 'Amit',  34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rahul', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gaur',  10 FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE`, table `A` contains:

| NAME | MARKS |
| --- | --- |
| Amit | -11 |
| Rahul | 2 |
| Gaur | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cSQ7-8RO)

Comment: What if i need to insert these data into Another table ? Inside this merge can we add that this calculation is inserted into table called Git??

Comment: @Umesh [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the output you expect because your new problem is outside the scope of this question and I am not sure I understand what your new problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Just join the tables on name and then subtracts the values -

```
SELECT A.name, CASE WHEN A.Marks <> B.Marks THEN A.Marks - B.Marks ELSE A.Marks END Final_marks
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON A.name = B.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Marks = A.Marks - B.Marks
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.Name = B.Name
WHERE A.Marks <> B.Marks;
```